# Creating and solving a recurrence relation for sine approximation

Tags: algorithm, scheme, time-complexity, complexity-theory, recurrence

In SICP, there is a problem (exercise 1.15) that says

```
Exercise 1.15.  The sine of an angle (specified in radians) can be 
computed by making use of the approximation sin x x if x is 
sufficiently small, and the trigonometric identity

sin(r) = 3sin(r/3) - 4sin^3(r/3)

to reduce the size of the argument of sin. (For purposes of this 
exercise an angle is considered ``sufficiently small'' if its 
magnitude is not greater than 0.1 radians.) These ideas are incorporated 
in the following procedures:

(define (cube x) (* x x x))
(define (p x) (- (* 3 x) (* 4 (cube x))))
(define (sine angle)
  (if (not (> (abs angle) 0.1))
   angle
   (p (sine (/ angle 3.0)))))

a.  How many times is the procedure p applied when (sine 12.15) is evaluated?

b.  What is the order of growth in space and number of steps 
    (as a function of a) used by the process generated by the 
    sine procedure when (sine a) is evaluated?
```

You can analyze it by running it, and see that it becomes `O(loga)` where a is the input angle in radians.

However, this isn't sufficient. This should be provable via recurrence relation. I can set up a recurrence relation as such:

T(a) = 3T(a/3) - 4T(a/3)^3

Which is homogenous:

3T(a/3) - 4T(a/3)^3 - T(a) = 0

However, it is non-linear. I am unsure how to get the characteristic equation for this so that I can solve it and prove to myself `O(loga)` is more than just "intuitively true". No tutorial on the internet seems to cover this analysis, and the only thing I saw conclusively said that non-linear recurrences are pretty much impossible to solve.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the computation with the amount of time the computation takes.

If θ≤0.1, then T(θ) is 1. Otherwise, it is T(θ/3)+k, where `k` is the time it takes to do four multiplications, a subtraction, and some miscellaneous bookkeeping.

It is evident that the argument for the i<sup>th</sup> recursion will be θ/3<sup>i</sup>, and therefore that the recursion will continue until θ/3<sup>i</sup>≤0.1. Since the smallest value of i for which that inequality is true is ⌈log<sub>3</sub>(θ/0.1)⌉, we can see that T(θ) = k*⌈log<sub>3</sub>(θ/0.1)⌉, which is O(logθ). (I left out the small constant factor which differentiates the last recursion from the other ones, since it makes no difference.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "Should be obvious" is dangerous language when talking about this kind of stuff. Would you mind elaborating so I can green check you?

Comment: @Steve: edited. Wasn't it obvious? :) Since this is a programming site and not http://math.stackexchange.com, I still left the formal proof as an exercise.